# TypeScript generics, constraint for function paramters in object

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typeerror, typescript-generics

## What I want to accomplish:

Let's say that there is a config with type like this:

```
type ExmapleConfig = {
    A: { Component: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => null };
    B: { Component: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => null };
    C: { Component: () => null };
};
```

so, generally speaking something of shape like this:

```
type AdditionalConfigProps = {
    additionalConfigProp?: string;
    // + more additional props that don't have to be optional
};

type ReservedComponentProps = {
    reservedComponentProp: string;
};

type ComponentProps = ReservedComponentProps & Record<string, any>;

type Config = {
    [key: string]: {
        Component: (props: PropsShape) => JSX.Element;
    } & AdditionalConfigProps;
};
```

I'd like to transform a config like this, but:

- preserve hard types for keys (`'A' | 'B' | 'C'` instead of `string`)
- preserve hard types for props (`{ type: "a"; a: number; b: number }` instead of `Record<string, any>`)
- make sure that transform function only accepts correct configs, that is:

  - it has `Component` property, and all other properties from `AdditionalConfigProps` with correct types,
  - it won't accept any additional properties on top of defined `Component` and the ones in `AdditionalConfigProps`,
  - `Component` function has to be able to accept `ComponentProps`-like object as first argument,

Transformation may look like this:

```
const config = {
    A: { Component: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => <div>abc</div> };
    B: { Component: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => <div>abc</div>  };
    C: { Component: () => <div>abc</div>  };
};

/*
    Let's say that it will extract Components, and wrap them
    with additional function so void will be returned instead of JSX
*/
const transformedConfig = transformConfig(config);

// typeof transformedConfig
type ResultType = {
    A: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => void;
    B: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => void;
    C: () => void;
};
```

Please notice that:

- Hard types for keys 'A' | 'B' | 'C' were preserved
- Hard types for 'props' were preserved

## Approach I've tried:

```
import React from "react";

type AdditionalConfigProps = {
    additionalConfigProp?: string;
};

type ReservedComponentProps = {
    reservedComponentProp: string;
};

const CORRECT_CONFIG = {
    A: {
        Component: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => null,
        additionalConfigProp: "abc"
    },
    B: { Component: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => null },
    C: { Component: (props: { reservedComponentProp: "c"; a: string }) => null },
    D: { Component: (props: {}) => null },
    E: { Component: () => null }
};

const BAD_CONFIG = {
    // Missing Component or other required config prop
    A: {},
    // Bad additionalConfigProp
    B: { Component: () => null, additionalConfigProp: 123 },
    // Bad Component
    C: { Component: 123 },
    // Bad component props type
    D: { Component: (props: boolean) => null },
    // Unexpected 'unknownProp'
    E: { Component: () => null, unknownProp: 123 },
    // Bad 'reservedProp'
    F: { Component: (props: { reservedProp: number }) => null }
};

function configParser<
    Keys extends string,
    ComponentPropsMap extends {
        [Key in Keys]: ReservedComponentProps & Record<string, any>;
    }
>(config: {
    [Key in Keys]: {
        Component: (props?: ComponentPropsMap[Keys]) => React.ReactNode;
    } & AdditionalConfigProps;
}) {
    /*
        TODO: Transform config.
        For now we want to make sure that TS is even able to 'see' it correctly.
    */
    return config;
}

/*
    ❌ Throws unexpected type error
*/
const result = configParser(CORRECT_CONFIG);

// Expected typeof result (what I'd want)
type ExpectedResultType = {
    A: {
        Component: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => null;
        additionalConfigProp: "abc";
    };
    B: { Component: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => null };
    C: { Component: (props: { reservedComponentProp: "c"; a: string }) => null };
    D: { Component: (props: {}) => null };
    E: { Component: () => null };
};

/*
    ❌ Should throw type errors, but not the ones it does
*/
configParser(BAD_CONFIG);
```

Of course I could do something like this:

```
function configParser<
    Config extends {
        [key: string]: {
            Component: (componentProps: any) => React.ReactNode;
        };
    }
>(config: Config) {
    return config;
}

// No type error, result type as expected
const result = configParser(CORRECT_CONFIG);
```

but it:

- wouldn't validate `componentProps` (maybe `componentProps: Record<string, any> & ReservedComponentProps` would, but for some reason it wouldn't accept `CORRECT_CONFIG`)
- would allow any additional config properties

Comment: The term "hard type" is unconventional.  Perhaps you want to say "strong type" or "narrow type"

Comment: You have quite a few simultaneous constraints here, so instead of just writing up an answer I'd like you to test [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgZ46W) first.  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining it.  If it doesn't meet your needs please [edit] the question to demonstrate failing use cases.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer. Very clever solution! I think I more or less get it, and I think it will work for my use case, but I have two additional questions. I wrote them here: https://tsplay.dev/Wyep6W . I also added some comments and small improvements.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I'm willing to spend the time iterating *past* your original question.  Your additional questions really look *additional* and thus out of scope. For example, if you didn't want `reservedComponentProp` to be constrained to `"c"`, you shouldn't have made that an apparent requirement of your question.  I am willing to write up and explain my solution, and you are of course free to take that and improve it, or modify it according to additional or different requirements.  If you still have followup questions you could make new posts for them. Does that work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, thank you for your help : ) I'll try to solve this myself, and if I'll fail I'll make a new post. Maybe your explanation will put me on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type VerifyConfigElement<T extends AdditionalConfigProps &
{ Component: (props: any) => void }> =
  { [K in Exclude<keyof T, "Component" | keyof AdditionalConfigProps>]: never } &
  {
    Component: (
      props: Parameters<T["Component"]>[0] extends ComponentProps ? any : ComponentProps
    ) => void
  }

declare function transformConfig<
  T extends Record<keyof T, AdditionalConfigProps & { Component: (props: any) => void }>>(
    config: T & { [K in keyof T]: VerifyConfigElement<T[K]> }
  ): { [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]["Component"]>) => void }
```

The idea is to:

- make `transformConfig()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the `config` parameter;
- [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to a relatively easy-to-write type that doesn't reject good inputs, in this case it's `AdditionalConfigProps & {Component: (props: any) => void}>`;
- check each property of the inferred `T` more thoroughly, by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) it from itself `T[K]` to a related type `VerifyConfigElement<T[K]>` where `T[K] extends VerifyConfigElement<T[K]>` if and only if it's a good input;
- compute the return type from `T`, by mapping each property of `T` into a function type whose parameters are determined by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the corresponding `Component` property.

The `VerifyConfigElement<T>` type checks two things:

- that `T` does not have any properties not explicitly mentioned in `AdditionalConfigProps` (or `"Component"`, of course)... it does this by mapping any such extra properties to have a `never` type, which will almost certainly fail to type check;
- that `T`'s `Component` method's first parameter is assignable to `ComponentProps`... it does this by mapping to `any` if so (which will succeed) and `ComponentProps` if not (which will *probably* fail? function types are contravariant in their input parameters, so there might be some edge cases here).

Let's test it:

```
const config = {
  A: { Component: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => <div>abc</div> },
  B: { Component: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => <div>abc</div> },
  C: { Component: () => <div>abc</div> }
};
// typeof transformedConfig
type ResultType = {
  A: (props: { type: "a"; a: number; b: number }) => void;
  B: (props: { type: "b"; a: string; c: number }) => void;
  C: () => void;
};////
const transformedConfig: ResultType = transformConfig(config);
```

Looks good!  And for your `CORRECT_CONFIG` and `BAD_CONFIG` the compiler accepts and rejects them, respectively:

```
const okay = transformConfig(CORRECT_CONFIG); // okay
const bad = transformConfig(BAD_CONFIG); // error
```

As desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4BBAExeBmAgDsUAbAMI9MwAOYAFHGADOcALxwA3lThwUbDl16DhYyRDAB+AFxxpMKMG6iKlVQHp7cANRwQ0Ruvace-OGClZGAALFHgWHgByeFCAN0YYCDgAI0YDH20qAF9bGnpGZGkkKHiWIXAeJG4YfRl5JRU4IiKSpDLcSG4qmqkTMwsrG2zcyjoGOHLO7trZBULi0snK6pm4ADJEJDRoFgAec0trABo1bloAPhGxxgA1YuBMWiFuEVEAUT4kEG7dgBU4JAADxgVRYslY3i0-Ger1WayoigmHWWMFMAAoAgZpKYUGcAJTyc5wWIQYAsOBZIlyRqIgDaAGk4FY4G9AWg+ABXFhIXYAayQtAgmDgvxO+CWXWq+DgAB84PzBcKIZpfDoXnpAucALqmLrxKAU9Y0xqqCXddEm1T+QKmcQoKAob4gqDSP608XIyUwfBa860gAMWoBwNBsjNK0CcEMp1ocFM4Z6WMtBLkRJJZMaWSoVG57PtjEwHO4GC0cAsuOkmGgIBhYl2jX+QJB3DBm22UD2CqFIpOyoy0N0EkjG0RCfRmJkOPxhOJpPJlPOaMt23VolM-xHcAZTO48oF3d+Orgd0sj1r70+32qbvpvopjTxpjpjOZXeFh-RADpv-bRNi4HaDpOsUrq-AyWrugmPrnCmaZzve1CISu5hwCurz1ModjME+SIVF6442koZb5KY+AoGQai6hyICpFApApFRNHFBSsFwLs7CxOcKDJGguz2BxRJZEcjQAEI4WOcAYoRiLXKRyQUSgpgHIM9FoIxtEsTO7HAJx3G8fxOmCcJWECOJnrmpJrHabpPF8QJCE5FQjjEQw3bltwlbVm0555OMhQcnwMC-PkGGNEwBFYjhskEOR9GKXA3DUbR9HJOpzFZKx6YsLYqhiZJE7-jJJEEPJcVKQM1iqWlBoZTOWU5RM6KZXOtg5I4jhUMh8DuZ5UDfO0q6mP5gXBeMCg9VWfXnmiaFiHiIydTwKECAA8ggCBvAIvwAPqrQAcgAYgAkgA4qFWHhQ0WGmuZ1QRZORHRWRCnVSl1WaamCUBXwxlWmoGj9mqsJSKRen4Jmv1wHlo63ai+XSS5SByS9-SHDYqHvbVn2JXwfAUpDplERJUmRURzQLN5sO1KRaAo8p1gfUSON40JjQACJmXhFkkw9ihY0z33440byc1Md2WTOzMObYXVwBAvIoLG40Oh5k01oOaKretm07ftx0nfNcDOfLivZpQssiUwbO7Sth2nedDhOAAssA0jSIMuFi-A0ByyEzFEAAjhywBEOSs2iNaBhhU+rNYc5InqP9kKquetSiaLKJNZL30nF4KraKnINwAAjAATAAzELcdOAn5IJo0hMw1z4tl5XseO1DifbM38AFYj7MZ-h8Ok8kEAQJ8uKsVL7dG04ACqXSAgwGBtHAkRFry3AQAA7twtSRMLg-c1POdwBvW+79TJcV1XHe12v5OtCw++NAdR-izzhVNEgLSLFTReJSYjVE+uNpaLQ8vAZIidlYVjVtNS21s9anUNs5YoOAoBUCAA)